# Best practices for backing up to Amazon s3 and a NAS

Tags: amazon-s3, network-attached-storage, cloudberry

I am new to cloudberry.

I have a scenario in which about 2.5Tb of data form a local server is to be backed up both to a NAS in the local network, and to the Amazon S3. This data is constantly changing by multiple users. What would be the best practices to achieve something like this with cloudberry windows server edition?

I would like to also keep some sort of versioning capability for the files in question.

Comment: Have you considered https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the repose! I have not considered the option you mentioned. I'll go ahead and do some reading on it. What would you consider the advantage of going this route would be?

Comment: The advantage would be it's built by AWS for your exact purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you take a look at [AcloudA](http://aclouda.com/) that can be used as hardware gateway that presents cloud storage as local DAS to your server and offloads data to the cloud.

It can be installed either in local server or NAS (it depends on hardware specifics that you use) as SATA/SAS HDD with connectivity to cloud (either Amazon or Azure) allowing to run backup jobs as it would be done to local storage.

Comment: Interesting. Does this solution require any additional hardware or software to implement it in the existing infrastructure?

Comment: AFAIR, it installs in your server into HDD slots and connects to the network. It's kind of hardware iSCSI gateway that presents cloud storage as local SCSI drive. That being said, I believe it requires only a couple free HDD slots on your server and storage on the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your file size and number of object Storage GW from AWS costs you on monthly basis and you have caching option which is good.

CloudBerry Backup has block level backup where huge objects can be offloaded on incremental block level basis (basically changes goes to S3) what gives you another recovery point.

There is also real time backup that you may want to try.

Comment: CloudBerry has many issues. Making long story short: emulating hard disk with WAN connection isn't a great idea.